# Injecting a CSS file for a bookmarklet in IE & Cross Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following JS code that injects a link tag complete with attributes and href into the head of a page, this code works in all browsers except Internet Explorer.

```
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.id = '_mgc_css';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
link.href = url + "css/bookmarklet.css";
```

What seems to be the issue is that IE doesn't refresh the styles on the page when a new sheet is injected. I have tried IE's createStylesheet() method and this doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas or suggesions as to what I can try to make it cross browser?

Comment: Is 'href' pointing to the right path? I just tried and your code worked for me in IE too.

Comment: It is different by versions. So which version of IE are you using?

Comment: I would like it to work in IE8+ but 7 would be nice too but not crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in IE8+ should work.

```
var headHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
headHTML    += '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="+url + "css/bookmarklet.css"+">';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = headHTML;
```

> **Edit:** or like this

```
var cssNode = document.createElement('link');
cssNode.type = 'text/css';
cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
cssNode.href = url + "css/bookmarklet.css";
cssNode.title = 'title_goes_here';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssNode);
```

Comment: The first point doesn't actually work, no CSS file is even appended to the head, however, the second option appears to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just change your code line placement

```
var url = "location/"
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.id = '_mgc_css';
link.href = url + "css/bookmarklet.css";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```